# How to send batch request by using AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, batch-file, request, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking 3.0 and I want to send batch request. AFNetworking 2.0 is support enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock not AFNetworking  3.0.

How can I send a batch of requests using AFHTTPSessionManager?

Answer (score 1):

In AFNetworking 3.0 there is not an API to do that. Basically this is because it uses `NSURLSession` instead of wrapping `NSURLConnection` into `NSOperation`.
You have some options:

- Use `GCD dispatch groups`
- Make your own implementation for wrapping `NSURLSession` into `NSOperation`, just need to make the `NSOperation` observe  the `state` `NSURLSession` property and add dependency between operations before adding to the `NSOperationQueue`
- Use promises, you can find a lot of implementations on GITHUB